# CSS drop down menu only shows a small rectangle where there are no links, why doesnt it work?

Tags: html, css

I have this html code and I need the Automobiles part to drop down but it just displays a small gray rectangle

```css
.sub-menu-caption {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.7;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2px, 4px;
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.sub-menu-caption:hover {
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
}

.sub-menu-caption a {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
}

.sub-menu a {
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.sub-menu-caption:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav id="main-menu" class="section">
  <ul class="parent-menu">
    <li class="sub-menu-caption">Automobiles
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="https://auto.ferrari.com/en_US/sports-cars-models/car-range/812-superfast">812 Superfast</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://auto.ferrari.com/en_US/sports-cars-models/car-range/gtc4lusso">GTC4Lusso</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://auto.ferrari.com/en_US/sports-cars-models/car-range/ferrari-488-gtb">488 GTB</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://auto.ferrari.com/en_US/sports-cars-models/car-range/488-spider">488 Spider</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I cant figure out why it shows just a small grey rectangle when I hover over it. Is something wrong with my .sub-menu-caption:hover .sub-menu part or something else? I am trying to figure it out but just cant. Thanks in advance!

Comment: your white on white menu is strange but its working, did you mix up the classes ?

Comment: .sub-menu-caption is like the button who holds the content, and .sub-menu is the content right?

Comment: yes well change `sub-menu a {color: red;}` or something, the links are bareley visible with that background color

Comment: https://gyazo.com/9a91c7b5a7fb869d50a70e67698f7bb0 it displays this when i hover over

Comment: well ok, thats a complete page you didn't show here so I had no idea where your problem really was, my guess now is either some z-index issue or your navigation bar is overflow hidden

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be working just fine based on the code you pasted. Try to run the code snippet and you'll see what I mean.
The white link color you set on `.sub-menu-caption` and `.sub-menu a` makes this tricky to see in the page so I've removed it, but you'll see from this screen grab that it works. I think something else on your page is interfering.

[screen grab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYKJL.jpg)